# Attacks on refugee homes in Germany

Tags: data-request, geospatial, germany, terrorism

I'm trying to find *reliable* data on attacks on refugee homes in Germany/Poland in recent years. I know that there were several projects initiated to collect such data, however so far I can't find the output anywhere. All suggestions are welcome.

There's a badly maintained (not consistently formatted) table on Wikipedia: [Liste von Angriffen auf Flüchtlinge und Flüchtlingsunterkünfte in Deutschland 2015](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_von_Angriffen_auf_Fl%C3%BCchtlinge_und_Fl%C3%BCchtlingsunterk%C3%BCnfte_in_Deutschland_2015)

There's a project bei ZEIT which collected cases, but afaik never published the data: [Es brennt in Deutschland](http://www.zeit.de/politik/deutschland/2015-11/rechtsextremismus-fluechtlingsunterkuenfte-gewalt-gegen-fluechtlinge-justiz-taeter-urteile)

Are there any other official/community-driven data bases?

I don't want state-level aggregates

Answer (score 5):

For Germany, you may be interested in [this paper](https://www.ifw-members.ifw-kiel.de/publications/refugees-welcome-introducing-a-new-dataset-on-anti-refugee-violence-in-germany-201420132015), which comes with downloadable data. The data describe individual crimes against refugees (no aggregates) in 2014 and 2015. Latitude and longitude of the crime scene are included.

Comment: This is great, do you know whether the authors intend on continuing this?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know, one of the authors (David) is currently working on another paper based on this data, using some more advanced modelling.

Comment: The data used for the paper is just the scraped data from the project that @sheß provides below. There is a public github repo with the data here: https://github.com/ax3l/chronik-vorfaelle

Answer (score 1):

The website https://www.mut-gegen-rechte-gewalt.de/service/chronik-vorfaelle collects incidents. Sources of reports are published as well. (I just realized that this is the source on which the paper and the dataset from the  post by @MightyCurious are based)

The google-maps-based project Kaltland-Chronik
https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=1SuyMXRcmoMkz4-AfJaxaHYWIkI0
collects entries, but is apparently not available for 2015 and before and is not fully transparent on how the sources are collected.

Comment: That data is publicly available (scraped) through this github repo: https://github.com/ax3l/chronik-vorfaelle